# One localhost on two PCs

Tags: connection, localhost, xampp, laptop, desktop

Today I got an idea, that testing my web apps on two different PCs would be even better if they both are near and if I could use my own localhost instead of hosting.

> i.e.:
>   1. My ASUS laptop runs Windows 7 and XAMPP for work with localhost.
>   2. My desktop PC runs Windows XP.
>   3. They both are connected trough router.
>   4. There some shared folders on both.

Now what I wanted to do is to lunch XAMPP on my laptop and try to view same from my desktop through http://localhost/, but only when XAMPP on my desktop isn't launched.

Is it possible? Or if not, then maybe there are some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an odd/mental idea - just put two entries in each machine's hosts file if you don't have common DNS - then refer to each by name - it'll be far easier. And no localhost only ever points to yourself unless you specifically define it otherwise at which point you're inviting a world of pain on yourself now or later - don't do that ok.

Comment: Great. Didn't know about such possibility. Thnak you. Just what i neede. When I have XAMPP working on laptop I just need to insert the laptop ip address to access it localhost, through desktop PC.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Eugene: Just to be clear: `localhost` only refers to itself. Put entries in your hosts file like "desktop" and "laptop" or "fred" and "ginger". Then you'll access web pages using `http://desktop/`, etc. Don't try to use `http://localhost/` except when accessing pages *on the same machine*.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, got it. I tried it today. Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another way to do this;

`ProxyPass /othermachine http:// otherhost/` on the XAMP apache config and there you go. If you were really neat, setup a virtual host with `ProxyPass / http:// otherhost/`